# String matching in python with re

Tags: python, regex, string-matching

I have a file in this structure:

`009/foo/bar/hi23123/foo/bar231123/foo/bar/yo232131`

What i need is to find the exact match of a string; e.g. only /foo/bar among /foo/bar/hi and /foo/bar/yo

One solution came up in my mind is like to check for ending "/" for the input string. Because if there is ending "/" in the possible results, that means it got something different than only /foo/bar.

For this solution, I must say that:

```
input = /foo/bar
```

and

```
match input without ending "/"
```

How can I do this by Regex in python?

Btw, if there any other solution suggestion, you're welcome to share here.

Comment: Do you not know how to use the Python regular expression methods or do you not know how to use regular expressions in general?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you want `/foo/bar` **not** followed by a `/`?  If so, then you're looking for a "negative lookahead",

```
r = re.compile(r'/foo/bar(?!/)')
```

and then `r.search` to your heart's content.